# Create a hardcoded Dataframe from csv in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**

I have a .csv/.feather/... and want to "hardcode" it for a StackOverflow Post.

```
id  begin_date  status
1   2020-02-01  a
1   2020-02-10  b
1   2020-02-17  c
2   2020-02-02  d
2   2020-03-06  b
2   2020-04-17  c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do that. Note: The dataframe shouldn't be too big, otherwise the post becomes very long.

**How**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"filepath")
print("pd.DataFrame(" + str(df.values.tolist()) + ", columns=" + str(df.columns.tolist()) + ")")
```

**Result**

```
pd.DataFrame([[1, '2020-02-01', 'a'], [1, '2020-02-10', 'b'], [1, '2020-02-17', 'c'], [2, '2020-02-02', 'd'], [2, '2020-03-06', 'b'],[2, '2020-04-17', 'c']], columns=['id', 'begin_date', 'status'])
```